# Is there a way to make shopkeeper always heard?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I really like the voice of the shopkeeper. Is there any way in Crypt of the Necrodancer to always have the shopkeeper's voice regardless of the distance from him?

Comment: You mean the shopkeeper music (as opposed to the normal level music)?

Comment: @joedragons I mean the shopkeeper's voice which in-game you only hear when nearby him, I'd like it to be always present like in the alternate OST files

Comment: Maybe http://www.technologytell.com/gaming/133140/add-custom-music-crypt-necrodancer/ will help you.  I'm not sure I understand your question but I think so and I'm just using different words.  So if you got the soundtracks you can put them in and hear them all the time.  If that does answer your question, I can put as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the shopkeeper version of songs, and use them as custom songs in the game ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RtzTEmc8vw)). Unfortunately if you're going for high scores, this will put you in a separate category.

There is no way to have the shopkeeper's voice permanently without custom music. If you're far away from him, he will get quieter- that is something that is hardcoded into the game.